# Add ViewPager in Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have two fragments: `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment`. `FirstFragment` contains `ViewPager`, which has three pages (three fragments). In the `onCreate` of activty, I add `FirstFragment` to main layout, and three pages show normally.

Problem is: when I replace `FirstFragment` by `SecondFragment`, and then comeback `FirstFragment` three pages disappear. Then I scroll `ViewPager` forward and backward, pages show but only first and third pages show, second page disappear.

Here `FirstFragment`:

```html
package com.example.bkmsx.afragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    static MainActivity mainActivity;
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(MainActivity activity){
        mainActivity = activity;
        return new FirstFragment();
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, null);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            String text = "";
            switch (position) {
                case 0: text = "First Page";
                    break;
                case 1: text = "Second Page";
                    break;
                case 2: text = "Third Page";
                    break;
            }
            return TextFragment.newInstance(mainActivity, text);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

`SecondFragment`:

```html
package com.example.bkmsx.afragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    static MainActivity mainActivity;

    public static SecondFragment newInstance(MainActivity activity) {
        mainActivity = activity;
        return new SecondFragment();
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(mainActivity);
        textView.setText("New Fragment");
        return textView;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `FirstFragment` , Use this code and try

```
public View view; // declare view as global variable

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(view == null){
              view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, null);
              mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
              ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
              mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

As Divyesh comment has good suggestion there is also need to add

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Comment: Raval Thanks, your answer is so simple, and save me a lot of time. But what `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` for?

Answer (score 0):

use `ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager() );` instead of `mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Hope it helps

```
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PaginationAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```